# Using Rackup in Sinatra - Cloud9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sinatra, rake, cloud9-ide

I want to use Rack in Cloud9. I created an archive called "app.ru" which code is :

```
class HelloWorld

 def call(env)
   ["200",{"Content-Type"=>"text/plain"}, "Hello World"]
 end

end
```

In the terminal I put :

```
abc:~/workspace $ gem install rack
Successfully installed rack-1.6.4  
1 gem installed
```

And

```
abc:~/workspace $ rackup app.ru -p $PORT -o $IP
[2016-05-27 20:47:15] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-05-27 20:47:15] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
[2016-05-27 20:47:15] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5150 port=8080
190.239.166.29 - - [27/May/2016:20:47:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0008
[2016-05-27 20:47:18] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000000a39be8>
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb:31:in `each'
 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/lint.rb:708:in `each'
...
```

that throws me this error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIaeF.png).

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Your image of there bug you posted does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed a couple of brackets around `"Hello world"`.

From a [blog post](http://chneukirchen.org/blog/archive/2007/02/introducing-rack.html) about Rack:

```
class HelloWorld
  def call(env)
    [200, {"Content-Type" => "text/plain"}, ["Hello world!"]]
  end
end
```

Note that `"Hello world!"` is mapped within an array, and rack is confused by finding a string there instead.